# What is the cardinality of a set that has no values?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If a set has no real values. and the conditionality accepts only real values. For example, set S is the set of roots of a function f(x). But the equation f(x) has no real roots. What then will be the cardinality of f(x)?

Comment: Did you find any members for the set?

Comment: Zero. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: This question doesn't make sense as written.  The phrase "and the conditionality accepts only real values" is not mathematical, it has no meaning.

Especially, the phrase "what is the cardinality of f(x)" makes absolutely no sense.  f(x) is a function, not a set.  Can you please rephrase your question?

Comment: I think it's clear that the question means: what is the cardinality of $\{x \in S \mid \phi(x)\}$ when $\phi(x)$ is only satisfied on the reals and $S$ contains no reals?